# Locate symlinked binary with whereis

Tags: macos

On OSX I have installed imagemagick with Homebrew. Now I wanted to locate where the binary was, so I used `whereis convert`, which returned nothing. Turns out it is located in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is in the `$PATH`. But `/usr/local/bin/convert` is a symlink.

Can't `whereis` handle symlinks? Is there something better I could have used in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which` also includes symlinks:

```
$ which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/convert
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lauri  admin  41 Oct  5 18:19 /usr/local/bin/convert -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-0/bin/convert
```

Answer (score 0):

Use readlink to view where a symbolic link points to: `readlink /usr/local/bin/convert` `whereis` simply searches for the name in a list of directories. Some users may not want `whereis` to resolve symbolic links as sometimes symbolic links may contain implementation-specific details (on one system the symbolic may point to X, on another to Y)

Comment: The problem is that `whereis` didn't find it though it was there (but as an symlink). Can that be circumvented?

Comment: @Znarkus not possible as far as I know, but you could report it as a feature request